# When is it necessary to use a Kalman Filter, and not a simple estimation method?

Tags: kalman-filters, parameter-estimation, bayesian-estimation

I know its a stupid question, but I got understand this very fundemental point. Say we have a sinousodial signal, which we want to extract from a noisy (known variance and mean) measurement. It is mathematically easier for me to write a maximum liklihood algorithm which converges to the amplitude, phase and the frequency, and simply calculate the real signal based on that. My question is, when it is necessary to use a Kalman Filter, and not a simple estimator? My only guess is computation reasons, as thanks to its recursive form, it is faster and requires less memory than any other algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

A Kalman filter can be run iteratively on data before you have all the data, or enough data for sufficient likelihood or regression fit.  A Kalman filter does not require storing all the data, but only recent data plus state.  In the case that your assumption of the data being stationary (say you assume a sinusoid of a single frequency) is false, the Kalman filter will track local in time variations, whereas a regression of too low an order (say linear) for the actual data may not.

Comment: Yes, but there are plenty of recursive estimators, that gets better the larger the data gets too. Also, the kalman Filter assumes that all the parameters in the measurement and process model are already known (which needs estimation actually), so what it basically does is just an extraction of an already known signal from a combination of signals, and it is needed only because the inversion of the measurment model is not possible due to the dynamic randomness in the gaussian noise.  I can't really find any "estimation" in what it does, for me it is just a statistical reconstruction of signals.